# Nested dictionaries in Python: how to make them and how to use them?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I'm still trying to figure it out how nested dictionaries in python really works.

I know that when you're using [] it's a list, () it's a tuple and {} a dict.
But when you want to make a nested dictionaries like this structure (that's what a i want) :

> ```
> {KeyA :
>       {ValueA :
>                [KeyB : ValueB],
>                [Keyc : ValueC],
>                [KeyD : ValueD]},
>                               {ValueA for each ValueD]}}
> ```

For now I have a dict like:

> ```
> {KeyA : {KeyB : [ValueB],
>          KeyC : [ValueC],
>          KeyD : [ValueD]}}
> ```

Here's my code:

```
json_file = importation()
    dict_guy = {}                                         
    for key, value in json_file['clients'].items():
        n_customerID = normalization(value['shortname'])
        if n_customerID not in dict_guy:
            dict_guy[n_customerID] = {
                'clientsName':[],
                'company':[],
                'contacts':[], }
        dict_guy[n_customerID]['clientsName'].append(n_customerID)
        dict_guy[n_customerID]['company'].append(normalization(value['name']))
        dict_guy[n_customerID]['contacts'].extend([norma_email(item) for item in v\
alue['contacts']])
```

Can someone please, give me more informations or really explain to me how a nested dict works?

Comment: Please explain what `{ValueA for each ValueD]}` is supposed to mean, as it is not a valid Python code.

Comment: @Maciek It means that i need to report the client name in reference of the contact present in dict_guy['n_customerID']['contacts'] . For the field contact i need to report the client name associated. Do you understand better or it's still not clear ?

Comment: Sorry, still not getting it :( Maybe write an example of how you'd like to use your nested dictionary? Something like `print(dict_guy[1234]['contacts']['guy@host.com']['name'])`?

Comment: Am I right that you want the `contacts` to be a dictionary?

Comment: @Maciek Yes i want the contact to be a dictionnary. Don't be sorry it's me my explanation are not clear at all, i'll try to write an example. Here it is : print(dict_guy['toto']['contacts']['toto@titi.com']['toto']) I need to have like the contact field is the key and the reporting ['toto'] is the value of that key. Clearer now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I hope I get it right from our conversation in the comments :)

```
json_file = importation()
dict_guy = {}                                         
for key, value in json_file['clients'].items():
    n_customerID = normalization(value['shortname'])
    if n_customerID not in dict_guy:
        dict_guy[n_customerID] = {
            'clientsName':[],
            'company':[],
            'contacts':{}, }  # Assign empty dict, not list
    dict_guy[n_customerID]['clientsName'].append(n_customerID)
    dict_guy[n_customerID]['company'].append(normalization(value['name']))
    for item in value['contacts']:
        normalized_email = norma_email(item)
        # Use the contacts dictionary like every other dictionary
        dict_guy[n_customerID]['contacts'][normalized_email] = n_customerID
```

There is no problem to simply assign a dictionary to a key inside another dictionary. That's what I do in this code sample. You can create dictionaries nested as deep as you wish.

How that this helped you. If not, we'll work on it further :)

EDIT:
About list/dict comprehensions. You are **almost** right that:

> I know that when you're using [] it's a list, () it's a tuple and {} a dict.

The `{}` brackets are a little tricky in Python 3. They can be used to create a dictionary as well as a set!

```
a = {}  # a becomes an empty dictionary
a = set()  # a becomes an empty set
a = {1,2,3}  # a becomes a set with 3 values
a = {1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9}  # a becomes a dictionary with 3 keys
a = {x for x in range(10)}  # a becomes a set with 10 elements
a = {x: x*x for x in range(10)}  # a becomes a dictionary with 10 keys
```

Your line `dict_guy[n_customerID] = { {'clientsName':[], 'company':[], 'contacts':[]}}` tried to create  a **set** with a single dictionary in it and because dictionaries are not hashable, you got the `TypeError` exception informing you that something is not hashable :) (sets can store only ements that are hashable)

Comment: Oh i see ! I get it wrong while we were talking i tried some change to my side and had a error TypeError : unashable type: 'dict' but now i see why ! here my error code : `     if n_customerID not in dict_guy:
            dict_guy[n_customerID] = {
                {'clientsName':[],
                'company':[],
                 'contacts':[]}}     ` I'll try your code now ! Than you

Comment: Well...It Works ! Thank you so much you just answer all my question about how a nested dict works i was wondering like for days how i will get to this results and finally you've enlightened my lantern (don't know if i can say that in english, it's a french expression). I have another question : How can i see how many levels are in my dict to be sure that it's correct ?

Comment: Best way to debug your nested structures is to use pretty printing - a way to display dictionaries and other things with a nice layout. Just `import pprint` and `pprint.pprint(the_dictionary)`. More on it here: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint

Comment: @CRC take a look at my edit concerning dictionary comprehension with explanation why your code didn't work :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and explanation ! You helped me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this page.](https://www.haykranen.nl/2016/02/13/handling-complex-nested-dicts-in-python/)

```
example = {'app_url': '', 'models': [{'perms': {'add': True, 'change': True, 
'delete': True}, 'add_url': '/admin/cms/news/add/', 'admin_url': '/admin/cms/news/', 
'name': ''}], 'has_module_perms': True, 'name': u'CMS'}
```